# Need to Upsert Data Using Tool Batch Wise

Tags: community, data-loader, metadata, informatica, jitterbit

I have order and contact object which have lookup from order to contact...I have Excel sheet which has order as well as contact information in it..I need to insert or upsert this excel sheet which should create order as well as contact based on excel info .I am trying tools like Jitterbit,Dataloader.io but not able to do it.
I am using tools because i have professional edition.

Comment: You will only be able to do one object at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is one time activity, you can ask Salesforce to enable "API ACCESS". They enable it for limited time . Contact Account Executive or log case to Salesforce Support(using help link). They you can use Data loader itself for this.

Read below on Success Community to get more information about other tools available for this:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtqXAAQ

Regarding actual upload :

I would suggest to separate order and contact information into separate csv files. first upsert Parent(contact) record and then move to upsert child Order records using IDs of contact which which you've earlier uploaded